# How can you make this cyclesort algorithm work?

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, cycle-sort

## cyclicsort

i saw the concept of cyclic sort in a youtube and created an algorithm on my understanding .i couldn't find any errors but the program is not running[java](/questions/tagged/java). i gave it to the chatgpt and it didn't show any errors either. can you help me solve this

```
package bdsa;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class cyclicSort {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] arr= {5,3,4,1,2};
        cyclic(arr);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
    }

    static void cyclic(int[] arr) {
        int i=0;
        while(i<arr.length) {
            if(arr[i]!=i+1) {
                int temp=arr[i];
                arr[i]=arr[i+1];
                arr[i+1]=temp;
                
            }
            else {
                i+=1;
            }
        }
        
    }
}
```

im expecting a write cyclesorted array

Comment: Off-topic:  Well, ChatGPT is notorious for creating software that looks good, but doesn't actually work. So, I expect it would be poor at debugging software, too. (I wonder if asking it to debug software can make it worse at creating software.)

Comment: It looks to me as if your program is going into an infinite loop, possibly because of a typo. I suggest running the code in a debugger. Set a breakpoint on `int i=0;`. Then, run the code one-step-at-a-time, while monitoring the values.  Debugging is a good skill to develop. If you want to become a software developer, or otherwise regularly create software, it will be a necessary skill.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is not swapping with the correct index. By always swapping the elements at `i` and `i+1` you may get into an infinite loop, because the next iteration may execute that code again for the same `i`.

With cyclic sort, the idea is to move the inspected value to its *final* position. This is not necessarily `i+1`. In your case (where the input consists of `1..n` values), we can know its final position by looking at the *value*. More specifically, the value at `a[i]` should be moved to index `a[i] - 1`. So that is the index you should swap with.

Here is the correction:

```
    static void cyclic(int[] arr) {
        int i = 0;
        while (i < arr.length) {
            if (arr[i] != i + 1) {
                // Get the index where this value should end up
                int j = arr[i] - 1;
                int temp = arr[i];
                arr[i] = arr[j];
                arr[j] = temp;
            }
            else {
                i++;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm missing something. This works if `arr` has `n` elements, with values from `1` to `n`, in any order. But, if that is not the case, an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` is thrown. For example, it won't work on `{400,35, 24, 90, 80, 52, 67, 88}`. Of course, this same issue is with the O/P code.